# Equivalence in the definitions of isometric and and isometric isomorphism.

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Given two vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ equipped with norm $|| \cdot||_X$ and $|| \cdot||_Y$, respectively.
I want to know whether the following statements are equivalent.

(1). $X$ and $Y$ are isometric.

(2). There exists a isometric isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

(3). $X$ and $Y$ are isometrically isomorphic.

I have checked the wiki, and found that (1) is equivalent to *there exists a bijective mapping $f$ which preserves the distance, i.e.,*
$$d_Y(f(a),f(b))=d_X(a,b), \forall a,b \in X.$$

Also, (2) is equivalent to  *there exists a bijective linear mapping $f$ which preserves the norm, i.e.,*
$$||f(a)||_Y=||a||_X, \forall a \in X.$$

I am not quite sure whether the equivalent statements in wiki are correct. If true, can we say (1), (2), and (3) are equivalent statements?

Comment: (2) and (3) are just different ways of saying the same things.

Answer (score 1):

(2) and (3) are just different ways of saying the same things. (1) is implied by (2) since $$d(f(a),f(b))=\|f(a)-f(b)\|=\|f(a-b)\|=\|a-b\|=d(a,b)$$ (1) can be a property of metric spaces that are not necessarily vector spaces. So it is possible for normed spaces to be isometric but are not isomorphic as vector spaces. For example $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isometric (with the Euclidean distance) but it doesn't even make sense to say they are isomorphic as vector spaces since they don't have the same field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that (1) and (2) are not equivalent?

Comment: That's right. For example, a curve $P$ of length $1$ is isometric to $[0,1]$, but it is not a vector space, so (2) would not even make sense for it.